# Cosmos DB - Using Nested Query output in Where condition

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have two JSON documents in the same cosmos collection

JSON 1:

```
{
"source": "PlacedOrder"
"orderid":12345
"customerName":xxxx
}
```

JSON 2:

```
{
"orderid": "70029955",
"source": "ValidationFailure",
"_ts":1570804414
}
```

I tried the below query but I am not getting results

```
select c.orderid,c.customerName
from c
JOIN (select value t from t in c.orderid where t.source='ValidationFailure' and t._ts=1570804414)
WHERE c.source='PlacedOrder'
```

How can I get the customer name from JSON 1 based on the order id in JSON 2?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this in 2 steps First, retrieve the order that you want to retrieve and then issue another query retrieving the customer based on the orderid.

If you know the orderid ahead of time, you can even issue these queries in parallel using something like `Task.WhenAll`. Another option is to use the same logic inside of a Stored Procedure.

Comment: The problem here is I am not sure of the order Ids . It has to be dynamic way of getting an order id . Get the orderids of failed orders and fetch the customer details. Joining both the query is better as its being used for a report